# How can I strip all HTML (except em/strong) from a string in SQL Server with a function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, function, substring

I have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]
(@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
```

I need to strip everything EXCEPT `<em>` and `<strong>` tags.

Thank you

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xslt transformation via clr function (eg, the one from the MDS assembly)

**Update**

Here's the answer using the XSLT transformation approach: [How to remove all tags except for some using Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885300/how-to-remove-all-tags-except-for-some-using-nokogiri)

**Update 2**

Then the only option left is to use regular expressions. Again via CLR function.

[Strip all HTML tags except links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links)

**Installation of the MDS assembly**

[Deploy SQL 2008 R2 MDS Functions without MDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604371/deploy-sql-2008-r2-mds-functions-without-mds)

Comment: Will that work with badly formed HTML. I need to remove <a name=ED>adsf</a> the attributes are not quoted and there are no HREFs

Comment: Sql Server is not suitable for such things, but I'm pretty sure you can apply **HTML Tidy** on your input html string before submitting it for processing

Comment: Because this is part of replacing the old incorrect data with new data and the old data is very specific (ie: the html tags were in all caps and the ones I wanted to keep were lower case) I was able to do this easier by using PATINDEX instead of CHARINDEX - please see my answer.

Comment: I dunno what you're talking about.

Comment: My original question wasn't as specific as it should have been. I don't actually need this to work on all HTML. Just the HTML currently stored in the DB. Luckily for me, the HTML in the DB that I don't want is all in capital letters and the HTML I do want is in lowercase letters, so I'm still just removing ALL HTML but only when it's written in capital letters. I should have been more specific in the original question.

Comment: With regex it is much more easily achieved, the strip-all-the-upper-case-thingies part.

Comment: I don't know too much about Regex. But I know they're powerful and I should learn them. I accepted your answer since it's the right answer for what my question actually was.

Comment: I agree, you need to learn regex because it's the only way to go to process lots of textual data in order to represent it differently. And to get regex working in sql server you need to enable clr support and add an assembly with that function.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Below is what I used for my problem because my HTML is very specific. The correct answer for my original question is the one I accepted above by Denis.

The data I'm using is very specific.

The tags I need to remove are all CAPS ie:

The ones I want to keep are lower case ie:

So I was able to do this easily with PATINDEX instead of CHARINDEX:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTMLlinks]
(@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT
SET @Start = PATINDEX('%<[/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ    >]%',@HTMLText COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,PATINDEX('%<[/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ >]%',@HTMLText COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = PATINDEX('%<[/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ >]%',@HTMLText COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,PATINDEX('%<[/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ >]%',@HTMLText COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
```

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL function something like:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StripOutHTML]
(
    @HTMLText VARCHAR(max),
    @stripDisallowedOnly BIT
)
returns VARCHAR(max) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @Start INT
      DECLARE @End INT
      DECLARE @Length INT 

      -- Replace the HTML entity & with the '&' character (this needs to be done first, as  
      -- '&' might be double encoded as '&amp;')  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '&') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity < with the '<' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&lt;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '<') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&lt;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity > with the '>' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&gt;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '>') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&gt;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity & with the '&' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;amp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '&') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&amp;amp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace the HTML entity   with the ' ' character  
      SET @Start = Charindex('&nbsp;', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 5 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, ' ') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('&nbsp;', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 5 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any <P>, </P>tags with a <BR>, so they will be replaced with a new line in next step  
      SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, '<P>', '<br>') 
      SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, '</P>', '<br>') 

      -- Replace any <BR> tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br>', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 3 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            Char(13) + Char(10)) 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br>', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 3 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any  tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br/>', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 4 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            'CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br/>', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 4 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Replace any  tags with a newline  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<br />', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = @Start + 5 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, 
                            'CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)') 
            SET @Start = Charindex('<br />', @HTMLText) 
            SET @End = @Start + 5 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Remove anything between  tags  
      SET @Start = Charindex('<', @HTMLText) 
      SET @End = Charindex('>', @HTMLText, Charindex('<', @HTMLText)) 
      SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 

      WHILE ( @Start > 0 
              AND @End > 0 
              AND @Length > 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            IF @stripDisallowedOnly = 1 
              BEGIN 
                  IF ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<B' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</B' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<U' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</U' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<I' ) 
                     AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</I' ) 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
                    END 
                  ELSE 
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @Length = 0 
                    END 
              END 
            ELSE 
              BEGIN 
                  SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
              END 

            SET @Start = Charindex('<', @HTMLText, @End - @Length) 
            SET @End = Charindex('>', @HTMLText, Charindex('<', @HTMLText, 
                                                 @Start) 
                       ) 
            SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
        END 

      -- Remove any leading space/carriage return 
      DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
      SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)
         IF @HTMLText LIKE '[' + @trimchars + ']%' SET @HTMLText = SUBSTRING(@HTMLText, PATINDEX('%[^' + @trimchars + ']%', @HTMLText), LEN(@HTMLText))
      RETURN Ltrim(Rtrim(@HTMLText)) 
  END
```

You need alter the following lines so as to preserve the `em` tags similar to: ( `Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<B' )` : The SQL function does replace `<BR>` and `<P>` tags with a new line, but you can easily remove those lines if you don't need. Hope this helps you or points you in a correct direction.

```
WHILE ( @Start > 0 
      AND @End > 0 
      AND @Length > 0 ) 
BEGIN 
    IF @stripDisallowedOnly = 1 
      BEGIN 
          IF ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<B' ) 
             AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</B' ) 
             AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<U' ) 
             AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</U' ) 
             AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 2)) <> '<I' ) 
             AND ( Upper(Substring(@HTMLText, @Start, 3)) <> '</I' ) 
            BEGIN 
                SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
            END 
          ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                SET @Length = 0 
            END 
      END 
    ELSE 
      BEGIN 
          SET @HTMLText = Stuff(@HTMLText, @Start, @Length, '') 
      END 

    SET @Start = Charindex('<', @HTMLText, @End - @Length) 
    SET @End = Charindex('>', @HTMLText, Charindex('<', @HTMLText, 
                                         @Start) 
               ) 
    SET @Length = ( @End - @Start ) + 1 
END
```